# PageView animateToPage loading pages multiple times - Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have an application with four BottomNabBar items and PageView to display them. Currently the PageView loads cycles through each page when I select a page that is 1 apart. So, if I am on page 1 and tap on page 4, it goest through page 2 and page 3 before it goes to page 4.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jumpToPage` instead `animateToPage` for do it directly.